# hierarchy with parent and nested child id in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with the following schema

```
Name         STRING NULLABLE    
Parent_id    STRING NULLABLE    
Child_ids    STRING REPEATED
```

The table is filled with the following rows:

```
Name     Parent_id    Child_ids
A        1            [2,3]
B        2            [4]
C        3            null
D        4            null
```

I would like to make a query which could return not only child_ids but also their name, i.e:

```
Name     Parent_id    Child_info
A        1            [(2,B),(3,C)]
B        2            [(4,D)]
C        3            null
D        4            null
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(Child_ids), 
  array(
    select as struct id, Name
    from t.Child_ids id
    join your_table
    on id = Parent_id
  ) Child_info
from your_table t;
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]